# Heroku DB Connection Reuse with Sequelize

Tags: database, postgresql, heroku, connection, sequelize.js

Can anyone help me understand how to keep a connection alive on Heroku using Sequelize? Currently I am following the instructions on the Sequelize site to establish a connection to the postgres DB on Heroku.

Here is the link that shows the current model/index.js file I am following.

http://sequelizejs.com/heroku

In this example for the site. Every time we call global.db.User we have to reestablish a connection for each time we want to access the DB. It would better optimized if there was a way to keep the only connection alive during each client session.